# Algolia keeps displaying old product results, even after reindex and cache clear (Magento2)

Tags: algolia

I'm using the Algolia plugin for Magento2.

I recently moved from one domain to another. I've created a new index in Algolia, reindexed my site (including the "algolia_additional_sections" table), and cleared all cache, but I'm still seeing a few products that link to my old domain in the Algolia instant search dropdown.

My website is https://www.opulentjewelers.com

If you type in "just," you can see two products that link to my old site. Any ideas how to remove these old products from showing in Algolia?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you reindex your data with enabled indexing queue?

When you don't have indexing queue enabled, the deleted products might not get processed by the indexer (they are deleted, so there is nothing to process) and therefore they are not removed from Algolia.

If you enable the indexing queue and reindex your data, only available products will be indexed into a temporary index. When all products are indexed there, the temporary index will replace the current production one. So all inactive / deleted / disabled products will be removed.